# Gentoo fstab issues and commented out

Tags: linux, mount, gentoo

I'm installing Gentoo by following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mD6aAG7DNA
I'm at 17:20 but his fstab file looks severly different than mine. Does anyone know how I can fix it? I followed the instructions perfectly.
My fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# noatime turns off atimes for increased performance (atimes normally aren't
# needed); notail increases performance of ReiserFS (at the expense of storage
# efficiency).  It's safe to drop the noatime options if you want and to
# switch between notail / tail freely.
#
# The root filesystem should have a pass number of either 0 or 1.
# All other filesystems should have a pass number of 0 or greater than 1.
#
# See the manpage fstab(5) for more information.
#

# <fs>                  <mountpoint>    <type>          <opts>          <dump/pass>

# NOTE: If your BOOT partition is ReiserFS, add the notail option to opts.
#
# NOTE: Even though we list ext4 as the type here, it will work with ext2/ext3
#       filesystems.  This just tells the kernel to use the ext4 driver.
#
# NOTE: You can use full paths to devices like /dev/sda3, but it is often
#       more reliable to use filesystem labels or UUIDs. See your filesystem
#       documentation for details on setting a label. To obtain the UUID, use
#       the blkid(8) command.

#LABEL=boot             /boot           ext4            noauto,noatime  1 2
#UUID=58e72203-57d1-4497-81ad-97655bd56494              /               ext4            noatime         0 1
#LABEL=swap             none            swap            sw              0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/etc/fstab` does nothing, as every line is a comment (starts with `#`).

Follow the instructions in the [Filesystem Information](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Full/Installation#Filesystem_information) section of the Gentoo Handbook to create an appropriate file for the partition layout you chose earlier in the installation.

> **Creating the fstab file**
>
> The `/etc/fstab` file uses a table-like syntax. Every line consists of
>   six fields, separated by whitespace (space(s), tabs or a mixture).
>   Each field has its own meaning:
>
> 1. The first field shows the block special device or remote filesystem to be mounted. Several kinds of device identifiers are available for
>      block special device nodes, including paths to device files,
>      filesystem labels and UUIDs, and partition labels and UUIDs.
> 2. The second field shows the mount point at which the partition should be mounted.
> 3. The third field shows the filesystem used by the partition.
> 4. The fourth field shows the mount options used by mount when it wants to mount the partition. As every filesystem has its own mount
>      options, users are encouraged to read the mount man page (man mount)
>      for a full listing. Multiple mount options are comma-separated.
> 5. The fifth field is used by dump to determine if the partition needs to be dumped or not. This can generally be left as 0 (zero).
> 6. The sixth field is used by fsck to determine the order in which filesystems should be checked if the system wasn't shut down properly.
>      The root filesystem should have 1 while the rest should have 2 (or 0
>      if a filesystem check isn't necessary).
>
> **Important**
>
> The default `/etc/fstab` file provided by Gentoo is not a valid
>   `fstab` file but instead more of a template.